# プロジェクトの共通化について

Tags: objective-c, framework, ios10

Xcode10.1を使用して、ObjectiveCを使っています。
storybordは使用せず、xibとコードで画面を作成しています。

いくつかのアプリのソースが同じであることから、
共通部分を抜き出し、別プロジェクトとし、他のプロジェクトから使用できるようにしたいと考えています。

やり方はいろいろあるのかもしれませんが、ネットで探していきついた以下を試してみようとしています。
・workspace作成
　http://blog.9wick.com/2011/08/xcode-workspace-share-code/
　複数のプロジェクトを一つのwindowで開ける
　そのビルド結果をworkspace内で参照し合える
　他のプロジェクトを参照した場合、ビルド時にそのプロジェクトもビルドし直してくれる
　
　上記のようなもの…らしいので、
　プロジェクトAから、プロジェクトA-1、プロジェクトA-2（共通ソース）
　このように切り出して、workspaceにA-1、A-2を置けば参照できるのではと考えました。
　
　以下を参考にworkspaceにA-1のプロジェクトを追加しました。
　http://seeku.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/10/13/200814
　
　上記のサイトでは共通ソースはCocoa Touch Frameworkで作成しています。
　
　そこで
　疑問なのですが、workspace内で参照するためには、プロジェクトA-2（共通ソース）は
　普通のプロジェクトではだめなのでしょうか？
　
　上記のサイトでは「Cocoa Touch Framework」から作成とあります。
　また、xibなどViewクラスなども共通化可能なのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

特にフレームワークにする必要はありません。一つのワークスペース・プロジェクトから２つや３つのアプリケーションを作成することは可能です。

Xcodeのファイルの管理階層は
WorkSpaceが一番土台にあり、その上に各プロジェクトが、更にその上に各ターゲット（ソースナビゲーターの一青いプロジェクトアイコンを押し、隣のウィンドウの一番下にある＋ボタンでターゲットを追加、ウィンドウ左上で切り替え可能）、更にその上にソースファイル群があり、同じワークスペース内のどのターゲットにどのソースファイル（ストーリーボードやxibファイルも同様）が必要か？は設定次第で自由自在です。

参考にされたサイトは「更に別なプロジェクトでも再利用すること」を考慮して、プログラムの一部を`framework`として作成し、作成された`framework`を同じワークスペースの別`target`に取り込む様にしているのだと思います。
このメリットは、別なプロジェクトを作成したときにそのプロジェクトに追加すべきファイルは、`なにやら.framework`だけで済むということです。

ここから余談

一つのワークスペースまたはプロジェクトには、共通に使い回せるソースが一部あっても、大きくアプリケーションが異なるのであれば、ワークスペース・プロジェクトを一つに纏める意味はあまり無いのではないでしょうか？
参考にされたサイトで`cocoa touch framework`に共通部分をまとめた（追いだした）理由の一つだと思います。

その様な場合は`framework`というコンパイル済みのライブラリーを作成し、アプリケーションAと異なる用途のアプリケーションBで、それぞれ、共通部分だけを纏めた`framework`を事前に作成し、それぞれでインポートすれば`framework`自体は再コンパイルする必要もソースコードも必要が無く、動作も保証されているため手軽に使えます。

さらに、今まで作っていたアプリケーションA,Bの他にアプリケーションCを同じプロジェクトに追加したところ、共通部分にアプリケーションA,Bでは起きなかった問題が起き、共通部分を修正した場合にアプリケーションCを再コンパイルするにあたって、アプリケーションA,Bもコンパイルしなければいけないのではないか？と問題が複雑になっていきます。

このため、

- 共通部分はフレームワークに纏め、それをインポートし合う
- 最初にフレームワークを作るプロジェクトは必要だよね？だからどこかにフレームワークを作成するターゲットは必要
- それ以降は、作成されたフレームワークだけをプロジェクトに追加すればそれで充分じゃない？
- 一つ（のワークスペース／プロジェクト）に何でもかんでも詰め込むと複雑すぎて思わぬミスを招くよね。だから、一つのワークスペース・プロジェクトが管理するターゲットは必要最小限に

すると良いと思います

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。A、Bプロジェクトがあり、たとえばある画面の処理以外はほぼ共通だったとします。そこで、共通部分を抜き出したいと考えました。たとえばWorkSpaceAにはAプロジェクトと共通プロジェクト、WorkSpaceBにはBプロジェクトと共通プロジェクトを用意し、共通プロジェクトは同じソースにできればと考えています。これは「・共通部分はフレームワークに纏め、それをインポートし合う」に当てはまるかと考えています。「・最初にフレームワークを作るプロジェクトは必要だよね？だからどこかにフレームワークを作成するターゲットは必要」こちらがいまいち理解できませんTTすいません…。「・一つ（のワークスペース／プロジェクト）に何でもかんでも詰め込むと複雑すぎて思わぬミスを招くよね。だから、一つのワークスペース・プロジェクトが管理するターゲットは必要最小限に」は本当にその通りだと思います。勉強のため、ひとまず今のプロジェクトから切り出したものを別プロジェクトにして参照させたいと考えています。が、、「更にその上にソースファイル群があり、同じワークスペース内のどのターゲットにどのソースファイル（ストーリーボードやxibファイルも同様）」がやはりよくわからなくなってきました。ワークスペースに配置したターゲットからどのソースファイルをビルド対象にするかを指定できるのでしょうか？

Comment: 結果から言って、アプリケーション２つ。それぞれのターゲットだけがあって、フレームワークを作るターゲットは要らないと思います。Xcodeの左上、実行、停止ボタンの右に現在のターゲットを選ぶポップアップメニューがあるので、そこで、それぞれのターゲットに必要なファイルを追加するか、ソースコードを開いてXcode画面の一番右のグレーの領域四角の内側に右端に縦棒があるボタンをクリックすると出てくる領域で、このファイルはどのターゲットの時にコンパイル対象か？のチェックマークを入れられるので、このどちらかでアプリAにしか必要でないファイル、アプリBにしか必要でないファイル、双方に必要なファイルを考えて✔️を入れていけば、ちょっと慣れが必要なフレームワークの作成を行わずに共通ソースは同じファイルを参照してアプリを作成出来ます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。さっそく試そうとしているのですが、どちらもどのXcodeのどの部分なのかがわからず…すいません、キャプチャを張ってみたのですが、赤枠の箇所が「現在のターゲットを選ぶポップアップメニュー」でしょうか？

Comment: 仰るとおりです。iOSの場合はどのシミュレーターで動作確認するか？までがセットなので、ターゲットAのiPhone XR等を選択して下さい。

Comment: 選択してみたのですが、どうやって「それぞれのターゲットに必要なファイルを追加する」のかがわかりませんでした。。。Xcodeも不慣れなのでもう少し触ってみます

Comment: 画面を見る限り追加作成されたのがプロジェクトに見えます。同じプロジェクト内に、複数のターゲットが登録されていたら、添付スクリーンショットの一番右側にターゲットアプリケーションが２つ見える様になるはずです。プロジェクトとターゲットは異なることに留意下さい

Comment: ターゲット＝プロジェクトと思っていました。Чайка さまのコメントを理解できていないのかもしれません。・「右クリックメニュー->Add File to"ワークスペース名"」でプロジェクトA.xcodeprojとプロジェクトB.xcodeprojを指定しました。ソースナビゲーターの一青いプロジェクトアイコンを押すと、隣のウィンドウのGeneralのところには、PROJECTとTARGETがそれぞれ１こずつ表示されています。しかし、そもそも登録の仕方などが違ったりしますでしょうか？

Comment: そこまでは合っています。Project, Targetが縦に並ぶ欄の一番したにTargetを追加するボタンがあり、そこから新しいターゲットを追加出来ます。

Comment: プロジェクトAのGeneralにターゲットを追加してみました。（プロジェクトAのターゲットをDuplicateで新しく追加すると、プロジェクトAソースを選択すると、画面の一番右側に表示されるTarget MembersipにプロジェクトAと先ほど作成したターゲットが選べるようになっていました。ただし選択できるのはプロジェクトAのソースファイルだけとなっています。 Чайка さまのいうイメージとあっていますでしょうか？あくまでプロジェクトAのなかのソースだけが選択可能ということでしょうか？

Comment: コメントツリーが長くなってしまったので、チャットに移行しました